# Required (mandatory) Gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor

Is there any way to force a Gutenberg block to be on every page of a post type?

I tried to add a **template** on my **page** and it does almost what I need, but I can still remove my default blocks.

The closest I've come is this:

```php
function ckt_mina_init_required_block()
{
    // create a new page template (pages only)
    $page_type_object = get_post_type_object('page');
    $page_type_object->template = [
        [
            'core/group',
            [],
            [
                // add a paragraph block for the page summary
                [
                    'core/paragraph',
                    [
                        'placeholder' => __('Excerpt'),
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'core/image',
                    [],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $page_type_object->template_lock = 'all';
}

add_action('init', 'ckt_mina_init_required_block');
```

This will create a new page template and use it on every new page. The 2 blocks "paragraph" and "image" will be present in the first group.

**But** I cannot add any other block to my page.

Or, I can remove the `template_lock = 'all'`, but then, my blocks can be removed during the page creation.

Any idea on how I might achieve to have 2 fixed blocks at the beginning of my Gutenberg area?

Comment: what problem does this solve? This looks like something that would be solved via full site editing, but you've implied this is actually something the user can change on a per post basis. Is this an editorial requirement?

Comment: The goal is to force the user to always set those two blocks at the top of the page content to keep consistency in the page design.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lock feature that can be toggled in the blocks toolbar which is marked up like this. I'm not sure in what version this feature was implemented.

```
<!-- wp:paragraph {"lock":{"move":true,"remove":true}} -->
<p>C1</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

To lock your excerpt paragraph I would do this.

```
[
    'core/paragraph',
    [
        'placeholder' => __('Excerpt'),
        'lock' => [
            'move' => true,
            'remove' => true
        ]
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

No fast and easy solution for you. Read discussion [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5208) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8112).

You may try to write some rather sophisticated Gutenberg code to implement this feature, or maybe you could implement some `save_post` hook to check saved block structure with `parse_blocks` and do something if they don't match your required structure. For example, prevent post publication or insert required blocks into content.

Comment: Yep, that's the kind of threads I saw. Only a few people interested so far and no promise that it will be implemented anytime soon.
I'll try and do my best to achieve what I need and will post the result here.